# How to remove an element added by JS

Tags: javascript

How can I clear the results from the div I'm appending into section?

The code part works fine, but I don't know how to clear the page

The html only has two buttons and a section to append the div to.

```js
const chars = 'ABCDEFGIJK0123456789';

const generateButton = document.querySelector('.generate');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear');

const section = document.querySelector('section');

const NumberOfCodes = 10;
const NumberOfChars = 8;

const codeGenerator = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < NumberOfCodes; i++) {
    let code = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < NumberOfChars; i++) {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
      code += chars[index];
    }
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = code;
    section.appendChild(div);
  }
};

generateButton.addEventListener('click', codeGenerator);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.textContent = '';
});
```

```html
<button class="generate">Generate</button>
<button class="clear">Clear</button>
<section></section>
```

Comment: `div` is not defined in the scope of your clearButton click callback. It's only defined in the codeGenerator function. There are several ways to to solve this. You could use querySelector in both callbacks, or have the functions share the `div` variable in either a closure or global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `section` inside your Listener instead of `div` because it is not accessible

Also you might want to remove the `<div>` created, , if so, use `innerHTML` instead

```js
const chars = 'ABCDEFGIJK0123456789';

const generateButton = document.querySelector('.generate');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear');

const section = document.querySelector('section');

const NumberOfCodes = 10;
const NumberOfChars = 8;

const codeGenerator = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < NumberOfCodes; i++) {
    let code = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < NumberOfChars; i++) {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
      code += chars[index];
    }
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = code;
    section.appendChild(div);
  }
};

generateButton.addEventListener('click', codeGenerator);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', () => section.innerHTML = '');
```

```html
<button class="generate">Generate</button>
<button class="clear">Clear</button>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
section.innerHtml = ""
```

If there was any error replace the section variable value with :

```
document.getElementById(<section_id>)
// replace section_id with id
```